# Deriving the Area of a Sector of an Ellipse

Tags: geometry

A sector $P_1OP_2$ of an ellipse is given by angles $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$.

[image: A sector of an ellipse]

Could you please explain me how to find the area of a sector of an ellipse?

Answer (score 10):

Scale the entire figure along the $y$ direction by a factor of $a/b$. The ellipse becomes a circle of radius $a$, and the two angles become $\tan^{-1}(\frac ab\tan\theta_1)$ and $\tan^{-1}(\frac ab\tan \theta_2)$. The area of the original elliptical sector is $b/a$ times the area of the circular sector between these two angles, which is straightforward to find.

Comment: I think you want to multiply $y$ by a factor $\frac ab$ to make a circle, so the fractions inside the $\arctan$s should be inverted.

Answer (score 3):

As I show in [Evaluating $\int_a^b \frac12 r^2\ \mathrm d\theta$ to find the area of an ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493104) the area 
of an ellipse given its central angle is:

$A(\theta) = \frac{1}{2} a b \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a \tan (\theta )}{b}\right)$

for $0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$, so the area of the sector in question is:

$A\left(\theta _2\right) - A\left(\theta _1\right)$

or:

$\frac{1}{2} a b \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a \tan \left(\theta 
_2\right)}{b}\right)-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a \tan \left(\theta 
_1\right)}{b}\right)\right)$

which sadly does not appear to simplify any further.

Answer (score -1):

Using polar elliptical coordinates:$$x=a\rho cos(\theta)$$
$$y=b \rho sin(\theta)$$
the part of the plane enclosed from the ellipse is
$$\{(\rho,\theta):0\le \rho \le 1,\theta\in(0,2\pi)\}$$
the Jacobian of the inverse transform is:
$$J=\begin{bmatrix}a cos(\theta) & -a \rho sin(\theta) \\ b sin(\theta) & b \rho cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}$$
so the area of a sector is:
$$\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}d\theta \int_0^1 d\rho a b\rho$$

Because the integral in $d\rho$ is $\frac{1}{2}ab$
the result is $$\frac{1}{2}ab(\theta_2-\theta_1)$$

Comment: I don't think this is correct. In your coordinate system, the line joining the origin to the point $(x,y) = (a\rho\cos\theta, b\rho\sin\theta)$ does not subtend an angle of $\theta$ with the $x$-axis, so your limits of integration won't be the $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ given in the figure.

Comment: No it's correct; actually this is true if $\theta_1,\theta_2$ are the eccentric angles of the corresponding points. (So it's not actually a polar coordinate system, rather a distance from centre - eccentric angle coordinate system proof.) Nice elegant rigorous proof.

Comment: The formula is incorrect for the definition of theta1 and theta2 given in the OP. I make the same mistake at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1651008/2469 and there are other linked answers where someone makes the same mistake.

Comment: It is incorrect -- if it were correct, then the area from 0 to π/4 is the same as the area from π/4 to π/2, which is obviously not true.