# Find angle given arc length and radius

Tags: conic-sections

I've got a function, $r(\theta)$, of the radius of an ellipse relative to one focus of the ellipse:
$$
r(\theta) = \frac{l}{1 - e\cos \theta}
$$
where $e$ is the eccentricity and $l$ is the semi-latus rectum.

I've also found an equation for the arc length from $\theta = 0$ as a function of time, $L(t)$. ($L(t)$ is a bit of a mess, so I'll leave it out unless someone wants to see it).

I'm trying to find $\theta$ as a function of $t$, so that I can use that in conjunction with my ellipse equation to find a parametric form of the ellipse, $\bigl(r(t),\,\theta(t)\bigr)$. The only way that I can think to do this is to solve the equation
$$
L(t) = \int_0^t \!\sqrt{r^2 + \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\right)^2}\mathrm\;{d}\theta
$$
for $\theta$. However, this is proving to be beyond both my and Mathematica's abilities. Is there a better way to get $\theta(t)$?

Comment: The question's still a bit on the vague side. Do you know the usual polar form for an ellipse?

Comment: What can I add to make the question more specific?

Comment: Well, time only makes sense if something physical is going on. Is it? What exactly is your goal? Yes, revealing $L$ would probably be a good idea, if you say where it comes from and what it means.

Comment: There is a slight difference to the question @MvG linked to. Here the radius is given as measured relative to one focal point. There the radius is given as measure relative to the center.

Comment: @WillieWong: I agree that this is not *exactly* the same problem. However, once that problem is solved, one can convert the solution to the focus-centered system. [This post of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1007302/35416) for example has a line about the relation between eccentric anomaly $\varphi$ (for circle from center, which is easier to find than actual angle, since $E(\varphi\,|\,m)$ uses it) and true anomaly $\theta$ (from focus): $$\tan\frac \varphi2=\sqrt{\frac{1-e}{1+e}}\tan\frac\theta2$$