# Given area of sector and a starting angle from focus of an ellipse, finding angle needed to get area.

Tags: calculus, geometry, conic-sections

[image: Description of my question]

**Problem Background:**

I'm trying to make a rough simulation of Kepler's second law (equal areas over equal time) and to do this I've divided the area of the ellipse into some number of pieces. I want to figure out how much I need to increase the angle by so that it sweeps an arc which forms a sector that has an area equal the slice area (which is (Area of Ellipse/n)

I am representing this ellipse with the polar equation for an ellipse from:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html

[image: Equation for radius of ellipse from focus]

where e is the eccentricity of the ellipse.

This question:

[How to calculate ellipse sector area *from a focus*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388134/how-to-calculate-ellipse-sector-area-from-a-focus)

describes solving the area given the angle, how do I approach this if I am trying to solve for change in theta while knowing the area that I want to solve for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wrote [a new answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1007302/35416) to [the question you referenced](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/388134/35416). That post describes how you can get from [true anomaly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_anomaly) $\theta$ via [eccentric anomaly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentric_anomaly) $E$ to [mean anomaly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_anomaly) $M$ which is proportional to both area and time.

To find the change in true anomaly $\theta$ corresponding to a given change in area, you'd first turn the original angle $\theta_1$ into some mean anomaly $M_1$, then you'd add to that and try to reverse the process, i.e. compute $\theta_2$ from $M_2$. But the relation between $M$ and $E$ is [Kepler's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation):

$$M=E-e\sin E$$

This is a transcendental equation. Wikipedia [writes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentric_anomaly#From_the_mean_anomaly):

> This equation does not have a [closed-form solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_solution) for $E$ given $M$. It is usually solved by numerical methods, e.g. [Newton-Raphson method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

The lemma on Kepler's equation has a whole [section on this inverse problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation#Inverse_problem), followed by one about numeric approximations. So I guess that would be the way to go.